# How to vertically and horizontaly align an image in the center?

Tags: html, css

I have tried every answer on this site but it's not working!

Tried helpers, absolute position and some CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Title</title>
<head>
<style>

body {

    background-color: rgb(18,19,19);
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<img src="image.png" width="513" height="396" />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For img to center you need a parent to hold it (with 100% width)

In the middle of the screen see example below.

For center of the row you can remove `height: 100vh;`

```css
.centered {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Title</title>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: rgb(18, 19, 19);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="centered">
    <img src="image.png" width="513" height="396" />
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will center any kind of element against its parent:

```
.centerElement{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

<img class="centerElement" src="image.png" width="513" height="396" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute` and give `top` and `left` to place the image in center.

**Better approach**: Use [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.image{
  position:absolute;
  top:46vh;
  left:46vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Title</title>
<head>
<style>

body {

    background-color: rgb(18,19,19);
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<img class="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png" width="50" height="50" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not working for some reason. Also the image doesn't stay in the center when resizing the window.

Comment: can you check now @Vulkan, updated. I have used vh and vw for viewport responsiveness.

Comment: @bhansa if I may, giving `top` and `left` alone may *not* work in all cases...

Comment: @kukkuz what do you suggest then, please tell.

Comment: See Elias MP's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46369599/how-to-vertically-and-horizontaly-align-an-image-in-the-center/46369641#answer-46369729)

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

</head>
<body>
 <div>
   <img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300" alt="">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

put your img in a  then make your image position to relative and use padding-top and padding-left to center your image in position you want!